# How to expire a key inside a hash in redis

Tags: c#, redis

I have a cache with Redis, using ServiceStack.Redis to access Redis in C#, I need to set expiration time for a hash, I've been reading on the internet that there is no way to set expiration time in a Hash, I should set expiration time in my keys inside my Hash.

I have the following code but its not working.

```
cache.SetEntryInHash(Hash, key, Item);
cache.ExpireEntryAt(key, DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)));
```

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342609/redis-expire-does-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way to expire key in hash and you can set expire for top level key [answer of owner](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/167#issuecomment-2559040)